# Inequalitiy word problem: why doesn't this inequality work?

Tags: inequality, word-problem

Problem:
Terry finds a pile of money with at least 500. If she puts 100 of the pile in her left pocket, gives away $\frac{2}{3}$ of the rest of the pile, and then puts the remaining money from the pile in her right pocket, she’ll have more money than if she instead gave away 500 of the original pile and kept the rest. What are the possible values of the original pile of money?

My solution:

Let x be the pile

$x-100-\frac{2}{3}(x-100)<x-500$

I wrote < since if Terry has more money, the pile is smaller. If Terry has less money, then the pile is bigger. Note: I'm interested in knowing WHY it is wrong.

Comment: don't you need to **solve** your inequality?

Comment: You have to write 'situation A money' > 'situation B money'. Your inequality is the wrong way around.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I've already solved it, the answer isn't correct, It results in x > 700

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I wrote < since if Terry has more money, the pile is smaller. If Terry has less money, then the pile is bigger. If you use > instead of > it  gives x<700, which is still wrong. The way I've written it it gives x >700 (this is wrong too)

Comment: Why are you subtracting $100$?  She still has the money in her left pocket.  Also, as Alexander said, the inequality is backwards.

Comment: @saulspatz  wrote < since if Terry has more money, the pile is smaller. If Terry has less money, then the pile is bigger, Anyway, I've just tried to remove the -100 from the equation and kept the rest as it is. Apparently it now results in the correct answer, thank you, even though I still have to figure out why I shouldn't put the -100 there, I now know what to look for.

Comment: The pile is gone.  Terry has taken some of it and given the rest away.  If you got the right answer with the sign reversed, then you made a mistake.  You don't subtract the $\$100$ because Terry *has* the $\$100$.